# Laravel 4 - Route [users.postUpdate] not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm currently doing a demo application on Laravel4. The demo application have some users in the database. I want to edit them one by one. I have a method "postUpdate", however, during editing (http://localhost/testlaravell/users/5/edit) an user from the list, I see the error occurs -

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Route [users.postUpdate] not defined. (View: D:\wamp\www\testlaravell\local\app\views\users\edit.blade.php).
```

I have the codes in the routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('hello');
});
Route::get('users/{all}/edit', 'UserController@getEdit');
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

In the UserController.php, I wrote the following script for edit and update:

```
public function getEdit($id)
{
    //

    $user = User::find($id);
    if (is_null($user))
        {

            return Redirect::to('users/all');
        }
    return View::make('users.edit', compact('user'));
}


/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function postUpdate($id)
{
    //


    $input = Input::all();
    $validation = Validator::make($input, User::$rules);
    if ($validation->passes())
    {
        //$user = User::find($id);

            $user = User::find($id);
            $user->username = Input::get('username');
            $user->name = Input::get('name');
            $user->email = Input::get('email');
            $user->phone = Input::get('phone');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->save();

        return Redirect::route('users.getIndex', $id);
    }
    return Redirect::route('users.getEdit', $id)
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
}
```

The code under edit.blade.php as below:

```
@extends('users.user') 

@section('main')

<h1>Edit User</h1>
{{ Form::model($user, array('method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => array('users.postUpdate', $user->id))) }}
<ul>
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('username', 'Username:') }}
        {{ Form::text('username') }}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:') }}
        {{ Form::text('password') }}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}
        {{ Form::text('email') }}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('phone', 'Phone:') }}
        {{ Form::text('phone') }}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('name', 'Name:') }}
        {{ Form::text('name') }}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form::submit('Update', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
        {{ link_to_route('users.getAll', 'Cancel', $user->id, array('class' => 'btn')) }}
    </li>
</ul>
{{ Form::close() }}

@if ($errors->any())
<ul>
    {{ implode('', $errors->all('<li class="error">:message</li>')) }}
</ul>
@endif

@stop
```

What I missed I don't know. Can someone help me?

Comment: Your route is not a named route. You have to name it explicetily in the router like : Route::post('users/update', 'UserController@postUpdate')->name('users.postUpdate');

Comment: A suggestion: you would probably want to use [RESTfull resource](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)  controllers instead of mixing basic routes with implicit controllers.

Comment: @naneri After implementing your code in routes, I get the error - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::name()

Comment: @Niladri ->name() is only avaiable in Laravel 5, not  yet in L4, I didn't know that :(

Comment: @naneri Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Route:controller` you won't have any named routes.

When you run:

```
php artisan routes
```

you'll see you will have `name` empty for controller routes, so you need to create routes separately, for example your postUpdate route:

```
Route::post('users/update', ['as' => 'users.postUpdate', 'uses' => 'UserController@postUpdate']);
```

**EDIT**

Example route list (however from Laravel 5 - so it might be a bit different)

[image: Route list preview]

You should also read carefeully @xAoc answer - probably it will be better solution (I almost never use `controller` method)

Comment: Thank! it works. However, the command "php artisan route:list" is not working. Can I use the command "php artisan routes" instead? Also, how can I see that the name (say, postUpdate method) is empty for controller routes. Can you post a screenshot for this?

Comment: @Niladri Please look at my edit. I've fixed that. Command `php artisan route:list` is available in Laravel 5

Comment: Thanks again! I understand the issue. But after hitting the submit button on the 'edit user' page, it show me the following error: 
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Controller method not found.

Comment: @Niladri If you changed only this in `routes.php` it should work

Comment: I have pasted the code you provided in routes.php, however, it shows the Controller method not found error (http://localhost/testlaravell/users/update?5). Here, "5" is the user id. Should I clear the cache before visiting the edit page?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you should pass the third parameter if you want to call route by name
Your code will looks like

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController', ['postUpdate' => 'users.postUpdate']);
```

The third parameter it is array, where key it is your **method** and value it is your **route name**

Comment: Thanks again! I understand the issue. But after hitting the submit button on the 'edit user' page, it show me the following error: 
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
Controller method not found.